# Access members of an object one by one

Tags: json, powershell, object, member

in Powershell I have an object from query response, and it contains multiple members. I have to add some strings before and after every member of the object, and then send the produced json as query to create similar rules for different service. What happens is that  $l_rules_json = $l_rules | ConvertTo-Jsondoes not access single member of the object but all members. How do I access members one by one in the cycle?

```
$l_rules |
    ForEach-Object {
        write-host("Output from rules objects in a cycle")

        $l_rules_json = $l_rules | ConvertTo-Json
        $l_rules_json_ext = "'{ `"rule`": { $l_rules_json }'"
        write-host("Actual json BODY:")
        write-host($l_rules_json_ext)

        $response_t = Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $api_uri_t -Method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType 'application/json' -UseBasicParsing -Body $l_rules_json_ext
    }
```

Comment: When iterating an array with `ForEach-Object {..}` you need to use the `$_` [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#_) inside the loop. Now you are using the complete `$l_rules` collection each time when converting to JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Theo, that's what I was missing...